# Catch collection was modified exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, c#-6.0

I have a scenario where I want to catch the collection was modified exception and retry.

One way would be to use when and match against the localized Message. This assumes there is a way to dig out the message.

I want to avoid changing `CurrentUICulture` as it can have side effects.

Hopefully there is a nicer way that I can't think of.

**Pseudocode:**

```
public void Refresh()
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e) when (e.Message == Environment.GetCollectionWasModifiedMessage())
    {
        Refresh(); // retry
    }
}
```

Comment: One way would be to make a method that forces that exception to be thrown and save the message  :)

Comment: When I saw a check for e.Message on an exception I assummed all "elegantness" was lost already :D

Comment: It's always a bad idea to rely on an exception message.

Comment: Could you explain why do you want to catch it? "Collection was modified" should be normally a [boneheaded exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) and you should not try to catch it.

Comment: @svick added some more text, hope you can make sense of my ESL.

Comment: @JohanLarsson Based on your edit, it seems you want an `IObservable<int[]>`, which you can then buffer and filter.

Comment: So, you're executing `source.Where(_filter).ToArray()` on one thread while `source` is modified on another thread? You shouldn't do that, since `ObservableCollection<T>` is not thread-safe. Retrying failed operations is not the right way to solve that, avoiding concurrent accesses is.

Comment: Hang on, why are you trying to catch-handle the collection was changed exception? That exception is telling you that you have a concurrency issue with your code...! IMHO, you should be examining how the different threads are adding/deleting/modifying the collection in question, and possibly consider making a thread-safe copy of the collection before doing stuff to it... Or at least consider using a collection that is not an `ObservableCollection`, which synchronizes to the UI thread...

Comment: If you're accessing the list in non-thread-safe ways and don't get an exception, there's *still* no guarantee that the results you get are correct and useful. The exception is pointing you to a problem, it isn't itself the problem.

Comment: Valid remarks about concurrency. I'm still curious about how to catch a specific exception.

Comment: Its hard to catch because you should not be catching it. Your code should never throw a `InvalidOperationException`, it should be modified to not perform the invalid operation in the first place.

Comment: Strange downvotes in my opinion. The question is about a general language feature. For the specific case: while it may not be preferable to locking it is an alternative for sure.

Comment: @JohanLarsson the downvotes are not strange. The question is though. You are trying to hide a well-known bug. The exception thrown could be more specific, although one can argue it already is - you tried to execute an invalid operation on an object. On what class, what method? Well, if you don't know, your `try` block or your method is probably too big, and you need to extract parts to different methods. One can argue you are trying to misuse a general language feature by checking the message and ignoring, instead of treating the exception as a blown electrical fuse (which it is).

Comment: BTW, that recursive `Retry()` will probably result in an infinite recursion if the bug isn't fixed. There other, safer ways to handle retrying for a limited number of times before failing

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the way to handle a specific exception is half-way what you've discovered already:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (SpecificException ex)
{
    ...
}
```

However, when you have to check the message you're in troubled water. There's no guarantee this message is in the language you've written your program in. Perhaps it might be for this specific error message, but it may contain a translated error message instead. If the exception type in question have other ways to determine which particular reason caused the exception, then these are usually a lot better. Look for things like HResult, ErrorCode, etc.

You would write this code like this:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (SpecificException ex)
{
    if (ex.ErrorCode == 1)
        ...
}
```

In C# 6 you can even write this slightly better:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (SpecificException ex) when (ex.ErrorCode == 1)
{
}
```

So, for this situation, which throws an `InvalidOperationException`, how do you *safely* and *correctly* handle this particular exception?

Well, **you don't.**

---

There are two reasons you might get this particular exception and message in a loop:

1. You're modifying the collection you're enumerating over yourself, ie. as part of the loop you modify the source collection
2. Something else (different thread) is modifying the collection while you're enumerating over it

In **both** these cases, the wrong thing to do is catch the exception.

The first scenario should be handled in such a way that you effectively do one of the following:

1. You make a snapshot of the collection before the loop and enumerate over the snapshot instead, tucking on a `.ToList()` inside the `foreach` accomplishes this:

   ```
   foreach (var element in collection.ToList())
   ```
2. You create a list of operations you want to modify the collection with, and only apply those operations after you have fully enumerated the original collection

   something like this:

   ```
   var toDelete = new List<T>();
   foreach (var element in collection)
       if (ShouldDelete(element))
           toDelete.Add(collection);

   foreach (var element in toDelete)
       collection.Remove(element);
   ```

The other scenario, **you really don't want this scenario**. The only way to fix this is to ensure you are using thread-safe collections and don't modify data shared by multiple threads. This is a recipe for disaster **even if you happen to not get an exception while doing it**.

Comment: Have an upvote my friend. I'm still curious about a way to `when` it :)

Comment: `InvalidOperationException` has a HResult property, but it doesn't seem to contain a known value.

Comment: Nope, it does, it contains [this: 0x80131509](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): UIA_E_INVALIDOPERATION, which is not helpful :)